# Radio button new value not updating after submission

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When I want to edit an object from a list (which is input via the text field and radio buttons), I can edit the text, but when I change the radio button value, it only shows the updated text value, and not the updated/selected radio button value. Any ideas on why its not doing this? I have tried chatGPT but I feel it always gives me overly complicated code (as you can see what I have already attempted!). Im a flutter noob so would be good to hear the reasoning behind any answers too.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
//import 'package:testy/page2.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
            },
            child: const TodoApp(),
          );
        },
      ),
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.yellow, fontFamily: "Whovetica"),
    ),
  );
}

class Todo {
  final String text;
  final bool checked;
  int priority;
  static int _tasknumber = 0;
  final int key;
//TODO: UNDERSTAND THIS
  Todo({
    required this.text,
    required this.checked,
    required this.priority,
  }) : key = _tasknumber++;
}

class TodoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodoApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<TodoApp> createState() => _TodoAppState();
}

class _TodoAppState extends State<TodoApp> {
  final _textyController = TextEditingController();
  List<Todo> data = [];
  int? _radioValue = 1;
  bool isEditing = false;
  int editingIndex =
      -1; // Initialize as -1 to indicate no active edit initially.
  bool isContainerVisible = false;
  bool settingsVisibility = false;

  final FocusNode _textFocus = FocusNode();
  void dispose() {
    _textFocus.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _textFocus.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        isContainerVisible = _textFocus.hasFocus;
      });
    });
  }

//clear completed tasks
  void deleteComplete() {
    List<Todo> completedTasks = data.where((todo) => todo.checked).toList();
    setState(() {
      data.removeWhere((todo) => todo.checked);
    });

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('${completedTasks.length} completed tasks deleted'),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Undo',
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              // Re-insert the completed tasks
              data.insertAll(0, completedTasks);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//Untick all tasks
  void untickAll() {
    // Create a copy of the tasks before unticking them.
    List<Todo> tasksBeforeUntick = List.from(data);

    setState(() {
      for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        if (data[index].checked) {
          data[index] = Todo(
            text: data[index].text,
            checked: false, // Untick the task
            priority: data[index].priority,
          );
        }
      }
    });

    // Show a Snackbar with an "Undo" option.
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('All completed tasks unticked'),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Undo',
          onPressed: () {
            // Restore the tasks to their previous state.
            setState(() {
              data = List.from(tasksBeforeUntick);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//undo deleted tasks
  void deleteTasks(int index, Todo itemToDelete) {
    setState(() {
      data.removeAt(index);
    });

    // Show a SnackBar with an "Undo" action.
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('Task deleted'),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Undo',
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              data.insert(index, itemToDelete);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    data.sort((a, b) {
      if (a.checked == b.checked) {
        // If checked status is the same, sort by priority
        if (a.priority == b.priority) {
          return 0; // Same priority
        } else if (a.priority < b.priority) {
          return -1; // Sort by ascending priority
        } else {
          return 1; // Sort by descending priority
        }
      } else if (a.checked) {
        return 1; // Move completed tasks to the bottom
      } else {
        return -1; // Keep incomplete tasks at the top
      }
    });

    priorityLabel(int priority) {
      if (priority == 1) {
        return 'High';
      } else if (priority == 2) {
        return 'Medium';
      } else {
        return 'Low';
      }
    }

    Color tileColor(Todo todo) {
      if (todo.checked) {
        // If the task is checked, use a grey color.
        return Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2);
      } else {
        // If the task is not checked, determine the color based on priority.
        if (todo.priority == 1) {
          return Colors.red[300] ?? Colors.red; // High priority
        } else if (todo.priority == 2) {
          return Colors.orange[300] ?? Colors.yellow; // Medium priority
        } else {
          return Colors.yellow[300] ?? Colors.green; // Low priority
        }
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("To Do List"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: settingsVisibility
                ? Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_up_outlined, color: Colors.yellow[50])
                : Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_down_outlined,
                    color: Colors.yellow[700]),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                settingsVisibility = !settingsVisibility;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Visibility(
            visible: settingsVisibility,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 40,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 7, 0, 0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      color: Colors.yellow[700],
                      onPressed: () {
                        untickAll();
                        setState(() {
                          settingsVisibility = !settingsVisibility;
                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.check_box_outlined),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      color: Colors.yellow[700],
                      onPressed: () {
                        deleteComplete();
                        setState(() {
                          settingsVisibility = !settingsVisibility;
                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete_sweep),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            //
            // LIST STARTS
            //
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 0),
              child: SlidableAutoCloseBehavior(
                closeWhenOpened: true,
                closeWhenTapped: true,
                child: ReorderableListView.builder(
                  reverse: false,
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                    setState(() {
                      if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                        newIndex -= 1;
                      }
                      final Todo item = data.removeAt(oldIndex);
                      data.insert(newIndex, item);
                    });
                  },
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (data.isEmpty) {
                      // Handle the case when the list is empty
                      return const ListTile(
                        title: Text("No tasks to display"),
                      );
                    } else {
                      //
                      //{STYLING} LIST TILE STARTS
                      //
                      return Container(
                        key: ValueKey(data[index].key),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          child: Slidable(
                              closeOnScroll: true,
                              endActionPane: ActionPane(
                                motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                                children: [
                                  SlidableAction(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                                    icon: Icons.edit,
                                    //label: 'Edit',
                                    onPressed: (context) => {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isEditing = true;
                                        editingIndex = index;
                                        _textyController.text =
                                            data[index].text;
                                        _radioValue = data[index].priority;
                                        _textFocus.requestFocus();
                                      }),
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  SlidableAction(
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        Colors.red[400] ?? Colors.red,
                                    icon: Icons.delete_forever,
                                    //label: 'Delete',
                                    onPressed: (context) => {
                                      setState(() {
                                        if (isEditing &&
                                            editingIndex >= 0 &&
                                            editingIndex < data.length) {
                                          isEditing = false;
                                          _textyController.text = '';
                                          _radioValue = 1;
                                          Slidable.of(context)?.close();
                                        }
                                        deleteTasks(index, data[index]);
                                      }),
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  color: tileColor(data[index]),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  //
                                  //LIST TILE STARTS
                                  //
                                  child: CheckboxListTile(
                                    activeColor: Colors.black,
                                    controlAffinity:
                                        ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                                    title: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Text(
                                            data[index].text,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: data[index].checked
                                                    ? Colors.grey
                                                        .withOpacity(0.6)
                                                    : Colors.black,
                                                decoration: data[index].checked
                                                    ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                                                    : TextDecoration.none),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          data[index].checked
                                              ? ''
                                              : '${index + 1}',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color:
                                                  Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                                              fontSize: 21,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    subtitle: Text(
                                        priorityLabel((data[index].priority))),
                                    value: data[index].checked,
                                    onChanged: (newCheckedValue) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        data[index] = Todo(
                                          text: data[index].text,
                                          checked: newCheckedValue ?? false,
                                          priority: data[index].priority,
                                        );
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Visibility(
                  visible: isContainerVisible,
                  child: Container(
                    // decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    //   border: Border(
                    //     top: BorderSide(
                    //         width: 1.0, color: Colors.black), // Top border
                    //     left: BorderSide(
                    //         width: 1.0, color: Colors.black), // Left border
                    //     right: BorderSide(
                    //         width: 1.0, color: Colors.black), // Right border
                    //   ),
                    // ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Radio(
                                value: 1,
                                groupValue: isEditing
                                    ? data[editingIndex].priority
                                    : _radioValue,
                                onChanged: (changedRadio) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    if (isEditing) {
                                      data[editingIndex].priority =
                                          changedRadio ?? 1;
                                    } else {
                                      _radioValue = changedRadio;
                                    }
                                    _textyController.clear();
                                  });
                                },
                                fillColor:
                                    MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
                              ),
                              //Text('High'),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Radio(
                                value: 2,
                                groupValue: isEditing
                                    ? data[editingIndex].priority
                                    : _radioValue,
                                onChanged: (changedRadio) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    if (isEditing) {
                                      data[editingIndex].priority =
                                          changedRadio ?? 2;
                                    } else {
                                      _radioValue = changedRadio;
                                    }
                                    _textyController.clear();
                                  });
                                },
                                fillColor:
                                    MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.orange),
                              ),
                              //Text('Medium'),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Radio(
                                value: 3,
                                groupValue: isEditing
                                    ? data[editingIndex].priority
                                    : _radioValue,
                                onChanged: (changedRadio) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    if (isEditing) {
                                      data[editingIndex].priority =
                                          changedRadio ?? 3;
                                    } else {
                                      _radioValue = changedRadio;
                                    }
                                    _textyController.clear();
                                  });
                                },
                                fillColor:
                                    MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.yellow),
                              ),
                              //Text('Low'),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    focusNode: _textFocus,
                    controller: isEditing
                        ? TextEditingController(text: data[editingIndex].text)
                        : _textyController,
                    onSubmitted: (value) {
                      _textFocus.requestFocus();
                      setState(() {
                        if (isEditing) {
                          data[editingIndex] = Todo(
                            text: value,
                            checked: data[editingIndex].checked,
                            priority: _radioValue ?? 1,
                          );
                          isEditing = false;
                        } else {
                          data.insert(
                              0,
                              Todo(
                                text: value,
                                checked: false,
                                priority: _radioValue ?? 1,
                              ));
                        }
                        _textyController.clear();
                        for (var todo in data) {
                          print(
                              'Text: ${todo.text}, Completed: ${todo.checked}, Priority: ${todo.priority}, Key: ${todo.key}');
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: '+ Add a task',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      focusColor: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    cursorColor: Colors.grey[400],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```